# Reading Geolocation from Quicktime Movies with Java (Xuggler)?

Tags: java, geolocation, quicktime, xuggler

I need to retrieve geolocation data from QuickTime MOVs recorded on the iPhone/iPad, from a Java application. I am currently investigating the Xuggler media framework; I was hoping I could use Xuggler's IMetaData interface to read out the UserData portion of the Quicktime file. Unfortunately, the only fields retrieved by Xuggler are "major_brand", "minor_version", 
"compatible_brands", "year", and "year-eng". I know from viewing the video's info in Quicktime that GPS coordinates are embedded. Exiftool also correctly displays the metadata.  I need to stick with Java for cross-platform compatibility (I develop on OS X and deploy to Windows and Linux as well). I know that Quicktime for Java is deprecated, so that's not a factor. Any thoughts on how to get the right data out of Xuggler, or how to use a different API?  As a last resort, I've considered parsing the output of Exiftool through Java, but that seems unpleasant and hackish at best.