# Reading geolocation data from a video file using FFMpeg/Xuggler

Tags: ffmpeg, xuggler

Using the MediaInfo application, I am able to see that a file taken with an iPhone 5 contains geolocation metadata, tagged both with **©xyz** and **com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709**. I am not able to find any way to get this data using xuggler, however.

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt   0000.00 (qt  )
File size                                : 7.50 MiB
Duration                                 : 3s 537ms
Overall bit rate                         : 17.8 Mbps
Recorded date                            : 2015-12-17T14:32:23-0330
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-12-17 18:02:23
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-12-17 18:02:27
Writing application                      : 8.4.1
Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime
Model                                    : iPhone 5
©xyz                                     : +47.5184-052.8046+133.390/
Make                                     : Apple
com.apple.quicktime.make                 : Apple
com.apple.quicktime.creationdate         : 2015-12-17T14:32:23-0330
com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709     : +47.5184-052.8046+133.390/
com.apple.quicktime.software             : 8.4.1
com.apple.quicktime.model                : iPhone 5
```

As an aside, there seems to be a lot of metadata on this file that I can't immediately find while debugging via xuggler.

The question at [Reading Geolocation from Quicktime Movies with Java (Xuggler)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561160/) is asking the exact same question, but has no answers or comments at all, and is over 4 years old.

Is anybody aware of a way to be able to get this data using xuggler as it is, or how I can modify the source and re-compile to make it work? I am required to get this data for a work project. Thanks.

Comment: it seems like an old issue https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4209